# How to count the POST request in bytes in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, arduino, webapi

I am using POST method to send the SMS using PLIVO but the problem is I need to know the Request bytes before sending from another tool which is Arduino . I could see in the Response debugger that Request.ContentLenght is 156 but this is not correct when we are supplying the bytes in Arduino

Please check the below code for Reference I need to know the Request with Payload size in bytes

```
using Plivo;
using Plivo.API;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PlivoSMSApp
{
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        bool isSMSSent = obj.SendSms("+91852762678", "+420603797597", "Send SMS using Plivo");
    }


    public bool SendSms(string from, string to, string text)
    {
        string authId = "TestAuthID";
        string autoToken = "TestAuthToken";
        RestAPI plivo = new RestAPI(authId, autoToken);
        IRestResponse resp = plivo.send_message(new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "src", ""+from+"" }, // Sender's phone number with country code
            { "dst", ""+to+"" }, // Receiver's phone number with country code
            { "text", ""+text+"" }, // Your SMS text message
            // To send Unicode text
            // {"text", "こんにちは、元気ですか？"} // Your SMS text message - Japanese
            // {"text", "Ce est texte généré aléatoirement"} // Your SMS text message - French
            { "url", "http://google.com/delivery_report"}, // The URL to which with the status of the message is sent
            { "method", "POST"} // Method to invoke the url
        });
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(resp.ErrorMessage))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why and where do you need it? Couldn't get it...

Comment: @tvdias i need it for my other tool which is Arduino in  which i need to call POST request before calling i need to supply the bytes of request i am sending ..So, i am using C# to check the request forming correctly or not..but i dont see request size

Comment: Can you please add the Arduino's code snippet? If I get it right, you're just using c# to calculate the post size? If that's right, it probably won't be the same on Arduino and c#. Also, you might need the body length or body+headers lenght, it will depend on how it's done.